# Display posts tagged as the page title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have one page template which is the same for all pages of the site.
As it is now, it shows posts from the category that has the same name as the page.
Is there a way to display only posts with the same tag as the page title?
Here is my code

```
<?php $catname = wp_title('', false); ?>
<?php query_posts("category_name=$catname&showposts=10"); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts("category_name=$catname&numberposts=3&offset=0");
foreach ($posts as $post) : the_post(); ?>


<div class="entry3 ey3">        

             <h2><span><?php the_title(); ?> </span></h2>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

            </div>

         <?php endforeach; ?>  <?php else : ?>  
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get posts by tag (from here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) add a tax_query to your arguments list

```
<?php $catname = wp_title('', false); ?>
<?php 
$args = array(
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $catname
    )
),
'numberofposts'=>3,
'offset'=>0
);
query_posts($args); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts("category_name=$catname&numberposts=3&offset=0");
foreach ($posts as $post) : the_post(); ?>


<div class="entry3 ey3">        

         <h2><span><?php the_title(); ?> </span></h2>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

        </div>

     <?php endforeach; ?>  <?php else : ?>  
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, Hugh. But i have one question, does this mean that i have to keep category too, because i would like my pages to pull posts by post tag only, so that they dont belong to any category in particular.
Let's say i have one page named "insurance" and it should display posts tagged as "insurance", without them belonging to the category "insurance", only tagged like that.

Comment: Hi,
No, the query I posted above will only pull posts with a tag of $catname

Comment: Ok, so sorry if this sounds completely retarded, but you are saying that i should basically just add your code to what  i already have so that it looks like this:
<?php $catname = wp_title('', false); ?>
<?php $args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $catname
        )
    ),
    'numberofposts'=>3,
    'offset'=>0
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );?>
<?php query_posts("category_name=$catname&showposts=10"); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts("category_name=$catname&numberposts=3&offset=0");
foreach ($posts as $post) : the_post(); ?>

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer above to the exact code I think you would need